# Как использовать free в качестве deleter'а?

Tags: c++

У меня есть примерно такой код:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[], decltype(&free)> information(malloc(arr_size),&free);
```

Но компилятор кидает исключение:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unique_ptr<char [], void (*)(void*) throw ()>::unique_ptr(void*, void (*)(void*) throw ())’
std::unique_ptr<char[], decltype(&free)>information(malloc(arr_size),&free);
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему происходит эта ошибка, и как её исправить?

Comment: А зачем вы используете `malloc` в С++? Всегда выделяйте память посредством `new` (прямо или косвенно), тогда и не придется разводить такие сложности.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В С++11 соответствующие конструкторы принимали первый параметр типа `std::unique_ptr<>::pointer`. В вашем случае это `char *`. Эти конструкторы не будут вызываемыми и в С++11 по той причине, что в С++ результат `malloc` типа `void *` не может быть неявно приведен к типу `char *`.

Начиная с C++17 спецификация несколько поменялась, но суть осталась той же. Соответствующие конструкторы `std::unique_ptr` являются шаблонными

```
template<class U> explicit unique_ptr( U p ) noexcept;
template<class U> unique_ptr( U p, /* ... */ d ) noexcept;
```

но согласно http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr, эти конструкторы участвуют в overload resolution только в том случае, если выполняется одно из условий

- Тип `U` совпадает с `std::unique_ptr<>::pointer`
- Тип `U` - это `std::nullptr_t`
- (еще одно условие, котрое не относится к делу)

В вашем случае `std::unique_ptr<>::pointer` - это `char *`, а `U` будет дедуцировано как `void *`, что не соответствует ни одному из этих условий. Именно поэтому компилятор сообщает вам, что в данном случае нет подходящей функции для вызова.

Если же явно привести первый аргумент к `char *`, то код должен скомпилироваться

```
std::unique_ptr<char [], decltype(&free)> information((char *) malloc(arr_size), &free);
```

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте явное преобразование в нужный тип любым удобным образом:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[], decltype(&free)> information ((char*)malloc(arr_size), free);
```